# Printing a potentially empty istream into an ostream

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to put the contents of an [`istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) into an [`ostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream). I tried doing that :

```
std::cout << my_istream.rdbuf() << '\n';
```

But when the `istream` happens to be empty, it triggers the `failbit` of the `ostream` (cf. [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), overload 9), which causes the `'\n'` and anything subsequent to not be printed.

Why does it trigger the `failbit` (what is the reasoning for doing that ?), and is there an other way to print a stream that doesn't consider an empty one to be an error ?

**EDIT:** To avoid the issue I could just do :

```
char c;
while(my_stream.get(c)) std::cout.put(c);
```

I would still be thankfull though if someone could point to me what was the reason that the comittee decided to trigger the `failbit` in case of an empty buffer.

Comment: Because that is just the way `operator<<(basic_streambuf*)` works: "*if sb is a null pointer, executes `setstate(badbit)` and exits ... If no characters were inserted, executes `setstate(failbit)`.*" So you will have to check if the istream is empty before trying to print it to the ostream

Comment: There are no "contents" of a stream. A stream is a flow of data. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica It is to make an auto-quoter function, that quotes objects if they contain "problematic" characters before writing them in an ini file. It was long to explain so I just made a snippet: https://wandbox.org/permlink/6nrfAM46gYnGAc65